# Android Images scaling

Tags: android

I always have problems when using images. I want to use an image as splash screen. So I imported all resolutions (ldpi to xxhdpi) of my image using Multisource-Drawable in Android Studio. Then, I created a imageview in my Activity and set Width and Height to 150dp both. It seems to use the ldpi resource and the image get very blurry.

What's the best way to import images in Android Studio to general use?

[UPDATE]

Android is chosing the right size, but not how I want. I fixed it by adding a 512x512 png file and then setting its Width And Height to 150dp

Comment: Don't give fix size to `ImageView`

Comment: It seems you did everything right, you should put images in different resource folders and android should figure out what image to use depending on the device screen density.. Setting a fixed size to `ImageView` has nothing to do with android selection an image from one of the resource folders. I guess you should verify that all images are in correct folders. Perhaps post an image of your resource folder structure and how you set the image resource into your `ImageView`. Maybe that will help us to find the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin they are. Android is using the correct image sizes, but  now the way I want, I'll update the post with my fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question may have two separate answers. First, you are assuming that an image is the best way to set up a splash screen. This is not so, as the content would have to be called **after** the app has already finished setting up. That would mean your user sees a flash (or more) of a blank screen before the splash screen is shown. Second, you would like to know the best way to import images into Android Studio. Here are the two different answers:

**#1** The best way to implement a splash screen is to have a theme called on a blank activity. The theme would include your desired image and background color. The reason for this is to eliminate the short break before content is called. [Click here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) for a link describing more and giving a tutorial.

**#2** In my opinion, the simplest and most robust way to add an image resource is to use the Image Asset import feature. Follow these steps:

1. Right click on "*res*" (in the Project View) -> *New* -> *Image Asset*
2. On Icon Type choose *Action Bar
       and Tab Icons*
3. For Asset Type choose *Image*
4. Choose the image path (on your computer)
5. Give your image a name (no UPPERCASE, only lowercase and underscores, etc)
6. *Next* -> *Finish*

Comment: I generally do this. But there is a problem with this method. The image I use is my enterprise logo. Its a round PNG with the enterprise initials on it. When I import the image using Image Asset it fills the whole circle with some color, erasing the enterprise initials. Thats why I can't use this method.

Comment: @MatheusNeves The only time I have had that problem is when I have the Icon Type set to Launcher Icons. If this is what you're doing, scroll down to Shape and select "None". This erases the preset background and leaves just your png.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the second option

Answer (score 0):

make image view height and width wrap_content and set its gravity to center..